# CakePHP 3.x, How to get full path to a template file

Tags: templates, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, filepath

I've tried `$this->viewBuilder()->templatePath()`, but this only returns the prefix and controller name.  (ex. `Dashboard/Users`)

The full path is more like `/usr/local/var/www/mysite/vendor/vendorname/users/src/Template/Dashboard/Users`

I've tried a few other things like `Plugin::path($this->viewBuilder()->plugin())` to get part of that path, but I have yet to find any piece of code that will return the settings for what the `src` folder is called and what the `Template` folder is called.

I could hard code them as `'src' . DS . 'Template'`, but was hoping I'd find something that would work even if those were changed through some config setting somewhere. (Ideally there would just be a `viewBuilder->absoluteTemplatePath()` or something like it.)

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve possible template paths via `App::path()`.

If you want to retrieve the template path for your `Users` plugin, then you could do

```
$templatesPath = current(\Cake\Core\App::path('Template', 'Users'));
```

This would give you something like

```
/usr/local/var/www/mysite/vendor/vendorname/users/src/Template/
```

It should be noted that this method doesn't necessarily return only a single path, it does so for plugin templates though.

If you need the path to an actual file, then you'll have to concatenate the remaining path segments on your own.

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Core\App::path()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Core.App.html#_path)**